# Find if a list is an ABC-triple

Tags: code-golf, sequence, decision-problem, number-theory

Three positive integers A, B, C are ABC-triple if they are coprime,
with A < B and satisfying the relation : A + B = C

Examples :

- `1, 8, 9` is an ABC-triple since they are coprime, 1 < 8 and 1 + 8 = 9
- `6, 8, 14` is not because they are not coprime
- `7, 5, 12` is not because 7 > 5

You can see this [Frits Beukers 2005 presentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20181227041615/http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Ebeuke106/ABCpresentation.pdf) for more details about ABC-triples.

## Input/Output

Three integers, decimal written. May be separated values or
list. Output had to be a truthy/falsy value whether the three
integers are an ABC-triple.

Note: It is important to respect integers order in the list, for example: `1, 8, 9` is not considered as the same list as `9, 1, 8` or any other combination. So first is an ABC-triple and second is not.

Thus A is the first element of the list, B the second and C the third.

## Test cases

Each of the following lists should output a truthy value

```
[1, 8, 9]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 6436341, 6436343]
[4, 121, 125]
[121, 48234375, 48234496]
```

Each of the following lists should output a falsey value

```
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 5]
[1, 9, 8]
[4, 12872682, 12872686]
[6, 8, 14]
[7, 5, 12]
```

Comment: Does the output have to be only one of two values, or can we output different truthy/falsy values for different inputs?

Comment: I think it should be consistent: your code have to output one kind of truthy/falsy values whatever the input. But the truthy/falsy couple can be what you want as far as it does the job: differentiate lists.

Comment: If we take the input as list of three values, does the input have to be in the order `[A,B,C]`, or are we also allowed to take the input in the order `[C,B,A]` or `[C,A,B]`?

Comment: You have to respect order since A < B is a criteria in the challenge.

Comment: @david `A < B` can still be respected when we take the input list in the order `[C,A,B]`. ;) But ok, perhaps it's indeed best to leave the input-order for lists-input as `[A,B,C]` to reduce confusion.

Comment: @kevin-cruijsen Yes and it's an ABC triple! with that particular definition...

Comment: @david Please edit that information into the challenge, to avoid confusion

Comment: I don't think requiring a particular list order is compatible with allowing input to be taken as separate values, as separate values are inherently unordered and [may be taken as a list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5437/12012).

Comment: @LuisMendo when in doubt, check meta: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>48 38</s> 29 bytes

<sup>-10 bytes due to [TFeld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38592/tfeld)'s `gcd` trick!</sup>

<sup>-7 bytes thanks to [HPWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz) for improving the co-primality test and spotting a superfluous space!</sup>

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to [nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34531/nimi) for suggesting an infix-operator!</sup>

```hs
(a!b)c=a<b&&a+b==c&&gcd a b<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDJboMwEL3zFS8RQrZwDhiHpYJcem1PPbY9GEMWNTERi0q/ntooBXoZvU3zRnOW7Vd1vY4jkZuCqlxmhedJv8hz5XknVUKiyPh4kxeNHGXtABd97ztkOzSVLJG5B5yq7rnWXaW71vg3eX8F@Rh2B5jgW9e8aLhoz/U3Bvg@tjDO1qJJI71WfdP8hCAbioFSuGbJo@XJwneABAwJQ0otZ4ZzhpBhv@aRCKNQBH8gnD3BEPDAjiU/CSLhJhfvH0ik0eKbOANfc77uMzw1J/3vSGIeJXxGy7Zouj4QsxCbXTY3CZ@OM//gCCJZwRQ13z7a50ONpoyzkP4C)

### Explanation

The first two conditions `a < b` and `a + b == c` are fairly obvious, the third one uses that \$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,c) = \gcd(b,c)\$:

Writing \$\gcd(a,c) = U \cdot a + V \cdot c\$ using [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) and substituting \$c = a + b\$ gives:

$$
U \cdot a + V \cdot (a + b) = (U + V) \cdot a + V \cdot b
$$

Since *the* \$\gcd\$ is the minimal positive solution to that identity it follows that \$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,c)\$. The other case is symmetric.

Comment: Also, I believe you only need that `gcd a b==1`. Since `gcd a b` divides `a+b=c`. i.e `gcd(gcd a b)c=gcd a b`

Comment: @HPWiz: Ah yes,of course, thanks! Will edit later when not on mobile..

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
Ṫ=S×</=g/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlW2wYen2@jbpuv/P9z@qGkNECm4//@voRFtqKNgoaNgGculoBNtpKNgrKNgCmObmRibGZsYwhjGYHETHQVDI0MQAVEH5phYGAHlzU2hLBNLM6CcJpcO2HggMoIoBTJgxgPZlkCbEUZamBuZWRjBWWZgGTOw4wxNwBxzoF6QfCyXpiYA)

#### How it works

```
Ṫ=S×</=g/  Main link. Argument: [a, b, c] (positive integers)

Ṫ          Tail; pop and yield c.
  S        Take the sum of [a, b], yielding (a + b).
 =         Yield t := (c == a + b).
    </     Reduce by less than, yielding (a < b).
   ×       Multiply, yielding t(a < b).
       g/  Reduce by GCD, yielding gcd(a, b).
      =    Check if t(a < b) == gcd(a, b).
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{(.sum/.[2]/2*[<] $_)==[gcd] $_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc6xCoMwEAbg3ae4oYhKiOQSo0KldOjWuUuQUlqVgraidBCxr26TkLocH/ffXdJXQyvXbgK/hmKdAzp@upgqLGOM1L6E3TUsCtXcH4bLWr8HCNrnqxpD2gxVH3yjEGYPYLxNcKCny/FM/dpbVsUIZATy0vMUEuAEEkcpuOSC/cFNWxBgyEyxU9YiQ52miZPIpY30EAF0RHdWM9fvbaeyFGWGm@ymtB9iwjjVeyYtfw)

Anonymous code block that takes a list of three numbers and returns True or False.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                              }  # Anonymous code block
                       [gcd] $_   # Is the gcd of all the numbers
 (                  )==           # Equal to
  .sum        # Whether the sum of numbes
      /       # Is equal to
       .[2]/2 # The last element doubled
             *[<] $_   # And elements are in ascending order
```

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pc6xCoMwEAbg3ae4QURLiOSSxgiV0qFb5y4SpLQqBW1F6SBiX90mwbocH/ffXdKVfSOXdoSggmyZ6PBpY5qjjjHL8oMO/SIyqO8PDX4xL9W7h7B5vsohonVfduF3F8HkAQy3EY70fD1daFB585IzAopAqj0vRwKcwH6lFFxywf7gti0IMGS2uClnodCkyX6VSKWLzBABXInrWcPUvLedUglKhZvcpnQfYsI6MXs21T8 "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 33 bytes

```
=AND(A1+B1=C1,GCD(A1:C1)=1,A1<B1)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

```
ÂÆ_*`\‹*¿Θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cNPhtnithJhHDTu1Du0/N@P//2gTHQVDI0MQYRoLAA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o6HZ4gr2Sgq6dgpL9/8NNh9vitRJiHjXs1Dq0/9yM/zr/ow11FCx0FCxjuaKNdBSMdRRMISwzE2MzYxNDGMMYKGqio2BoZAgiQGrATBMLI6CcuSmUZWJpBpIBKtFRMIKwjCAmAlmWQItgpliYG5lZGMFZIF1mYHcYmgCZ5kA9ILlYAA)

**Explanation**

```
ÂÆ           # reduce a reversed copy of the input by subtraction
  _          # logically negate
   *         # multiply with input
    `        # push the values of the resulting list separately to stack
     \       # remove the top (last) value
      ‹      # is a < b ?
       *     # multiply by the input list
        ¿    # calculate the gcd of the result
         Θ   # is it true ?
```

Comment: Oops.. deleted my comment.. >.> So again: you can save a byte by using multiples instead of swaps with product: ``RÆ_*`\‹*¿Θ`` [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeXhCf@DDrfFayXEPGrYqXVo/7kZ/3X@R0cb6ljoWMbqKEQb6RjrmEIYZibGZsYmhlDaGCRoomNoZAjEYBUgpomFEVDK3BTCMLE0A0voGOoYQRhGEMMMdSx1LGAGWJgbmVkYwRhgHWZA6w1NQCxzHVOgTGwsAA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Thanks! Yeah, usually when you have that many swaps, you're doing something wrong :P

Answer (score 4):

## Wolfram Language <s>24 30 28</s> 26 bytes

With 2 bytes shaved by Doorknob.
A further 2 bytes shaved off by @jaeyong sung

```
#<#2&&GCD@##==1&&#+#2==#3&
```

Comment: I think you should also be able to use `CoprimeQ@##` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @Doorknob, If the first and second numbers are coprime, are they necessarily coprime with their sum?

Comment: [They are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), but the original definition actually states that A, B, and C should be coprime. Most answers check only A and B just because it's usually shorter.

Comment: I think `GCD@##==1` would save 2 bytes

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```java
(a,b,c)->{var r=a<b&a+b==c;for(;b>0;a=b,b=c)c=a%b;return r&a<2;}
```

-1 byte thank to *@Shaggy*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVLBcoIwEL37FXupE6YRm4CIRTz2Vi/21ulhE2OLheCEYMdx/HYaEI8tHrLZnX3v5WWTPR5xst9@NzLHqoJXzPR5BJBpq8wOpYJ1WwKIsswVapDEtQBpG0UXpZc4xGXkwho0pNAQpIJKb7I6H9GASXEpxvgo0lQmu9KQRKyeEkwFFan0ZIoPIjHK1kaDGeOSJ5cmacUOtcgzCZVF67ZjmW2hcO7IxppMf75/AHpXa61nKNzBWv10BekcAUyn8GZq@3V67srNqbKq8Mva@gcnYXNNCl/7kjAa04XXk/5EcRrQ2R2oKAyiIGT9HgwyQso4c2tYu8WFMXei89k1CRfRP6y@c5vFC@aVGp4Fo3zYCeV3zILRBY3vun8851HMb0k0yInci7FwEDanM6fp9R/00vwC)

**Explanation:**

```java
(a,b,c)->{        // Method with three integer parameters and boolean return-type
  var r=          //  Result-boolean, starting at:
        a<b       //   Check if `a` is smaller than `b`
        &a+b==c;  //   And if `a+b` is equal to `c`
  for(;b>0        //  Then loop as long as `b` is not 0 yet
      ;           //    After every iteration:
       a=b,       //     Set `a` to the current `b`
       b=c)       //     And set `b` to the temp value `c`
    c=a%b;        //   Set the temp value `c` to `a` modulo-`b`
                  //   (we no longer need `c` at this point)
  return r        //  Return if the boolean-result is true
         &a<2;}   //  And `a` is now smaller than 2
```

Comment: `a==1` -> `a<2` to save a byte.

Answer (score 4):

### bash, 61 bytes

```bash
factor $@|grep -vzP '( .+\b).*\n.*\1\b'&&(($1<$2&&$1+$2==$3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5NboMwEEb3nOJbWAYaJdHYxhiVRD1CD8AGqJ0sUIgIyaKlZ6d2nSxG8@bvabr2dl77dsbRoa5Tl66u7edxAvtYTpO9Yvv4/kSaYbdpunz31lx8UNOlnGcZo5oJzhltmDgcmMzz1SXJacxy/KDzZjjvwXH/ZR/7y30YwDlsfx4xT3eLZYmFa4ebfcdvOAXBoAogIFFE0EpqqeiZZWgqkCAf/xsBlRF@VBYRVKWTJMifToKIIKKTUMG8PKYU2ogX6NDW/gtSgUoUfrL@AQ)

Input as command line arguments,
output in the exit code
(also produces output on stdout as a side effect, but this can be ignored).

The second part (starting from `&&((`) is pretty standard,
but the interesting bit is the coprime test:

```bash
factor $@      # produces output of the form "6: 2 3\n8: 2 2 2\n14: 2 7\n"
|grep -        # regex search on the result
v              # invert the match (return truthy for strings that don't match)
z              # zero-terminated, allowing us to match newlines
P              # perl (extended) regex
'( .+\b)'      # match one or more full factors
'.*\n.*'       # and somewhere on the next line...
'\1\b'         # find the same full factors
```

Comment: last `&&` can be changed to `&` because of [precedence](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>54 43 42</s>  40 bytes

*Thanks to @Shaggy for pointing out that we don't need to compute \$\gcd(a,c)\$. Saved 11 bytes by rewriting the code accordingly.*

Takes input as 3 separate integers. Returns \$true\$ for an ABC-triple, or either \$0\$ or \$false\$ otherwise.

```javascript
f=(a,b,c)=>c&&a/b|a+b-c?0:b?f(b,a%b):a<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDdCoIwGL33KXaTbPRZ7cc5JfNZtqVSiIuMrnr3NaWCmDDG4fx839mu@qkne7/cHtnozq33XY01GLCkPtk01Xvz0luT2eZQmabDBvTGkEofmbdunNzQ7gbX4w5TQApQSUjyzzNAHFC@xkvBJRf0C3jkEYAoo/MV5xdBKBZyRf5BopTBl0TFwmHxgECuFQt8Gd6yXkYVTCr2QzJyyeUbqIiEIuyac4T4Nw)

Comment: I don't think you need to test `gcd(c,a)`.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks! I've rewritten the code entirely.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>69</s> <s>67</s> <s>63</s> <s>62</s> 55 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:(c-b==a<b)/gcd(a,b)
from fractions import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/LDoMgFET3fsVN3EhD0/AQsal/0g1iaU18BemiX0/RWB9NCJmcGe4dho979R31prj7RrVlpUDhEutros9lUahbiS5PXSUBosjYvgVjlXZ1341Qt0Nv3cnHzr4f0WDrzoFJCAaJIUcroBgYhvQABGeCcfITbDM5BkLJdO1ezIRLGpJZuiieiyUQxUY146FBOBTtAT00CCAPNf@2yowKSVclNlvMfyJ8I1mYNyWR/wI)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>58</s> 51 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:(c-b==a<b)==gcd(a,b)
from math import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9NDoMgEIX3noLEDTR0wY@ITblJN6ClmogaShc9PUXTGmxCJo9vHjOP5R36eWLRqlsctTOdBhob3F5gezZK6atBSj3aDiaKCutnB5wOPRjcMvtwimXwr3ux@GEK0EKCgcSgQWgnFAOGQXUkgjPBOPkJlnU5BoSSteRvNsQlTd66@ireiN2BitLq8XkIkg7NR6TrMUgiTcr7v1zWVEi6K5H1xfY9wjNUp5mrN6H4AQ)

---

<sub>-7 bytes, thanks to H.PWiz</sub>

Comment: is the `gcd` in `gcd` trick valid? What if `a` is not coprime with `c`?

Comment: @jo-king If p divides a and c, it should divide c-a so b.

Comment: @JoKing: It is in this case, but not in general (you can prove it via Bezout's identity).

Comment: You can take it one step further and use `gcd(a,b)`, since `gcd(a,b)` divides `a+b`

Comment: It's shorter to `import math` and `math.gcd` in python 3

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
<V¥yU «NÔr-
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=PFaleVUgq07Uci0=&input=MQo4Cjk=)

```
                :Implicit input of integers U=A, V=B & W=C
<V              :Is U less than V?
  ¥             :Test that for equality with
   yU           :The GCD of V & U
      «         :Logical AND with the negation of
       N        :The array of inputs
        Ô       :Reversed
         r-     :Reduced by subtraction
```

Comment: [Here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=pVctVqlVPFapalU=&input=NywgNSwgMTI=) is another 11 byte solution, though on closer inspection it isn't much different from yours in its actual logic.

Comment: @KamilDrakari, had a variation on that at one stage, too. It could be [10 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=pVctVqk+ValqVg==&input=NywgNSwgMTI=) if variables were auto-inserted when `>` follows `©`.

Answer (score 3):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 34 bytes

Input is in unary, in the domain `^x*,x*,x*$` (repeated `x`s delimited by `,`).

`^(?!(xx+)\1*,\1+,)(x*)(,\2x+)\3\2$`

[Try it online! - SpiderMonkey (Mozilla Firefox) regex engine](https://tio.run/##ZY9Rb9owFIXf8ytCNcn3EpPWTgiByOtTJ/WlD1vfyia5wUm9mSRyTBVK@e3MMLoh7cHX1@fzsc/9KV9lX1rduUnf6ZWy67b5pbYHK76q@m7oAN7E5@vx4QfcjmAYIlyyMV2yiCIMYwS65EctWfJPh/H1G8au/easbmrAuDe6VJDRSYpYVK2FSrACjLBKroxuFCCORLMxpqjEDe50BaMKO292gEXgj1ALE/ed0Q4IJYixUU3tXkYieX/X/YN8ACk6aXt17y310813xA/wfAnYBSgvAfcAd93G9c7C1X3zKo1ehbrxyuIKizMwWJRt43SzUcU@cHa7WwsgA4mt6pR0IDHy8aIL5fk/pfTp19KVL2D9bOeH1@I0/i35Ik2vFiFZkEe78U1IsNiXp@vbv/nInbWtXRyZiQQJJyGJtsX@X8j9gdGczgNOEzr1NUuTLEnZeU@ClDLO/JoGxz3NuRdn0z9NOs8Czyj3lXs3o3Oanxz5jGc5/2iyIPN/sDSY0anXfgM)
[Try it online! - .NET regex engine with ECMAScript emulation enabled](https://tio.run/##bVBta9swEP7uX@GYQaRYMZHtOC/C64bpoNCwsQT2oclAcZREoMiuZKcuTv76MtluB2MTSHe65@6e5y7VwzRT7CbpiemcpsxevuqCnepSc3mwkzjJpM4EI91/xarC@84OpaDqvsoV05qbBJIKqrV9qnVBC57a54zv7AXl0gawPlNl6/iTc/sJ7nqgqly4xgO0xi6CoBpAgNZ@EwvW/oebQ5psFUv2YhsaVgHtLcutLpRhBxhp75HJQ3Ec@hC1@Ne8aAR4SXbKuWC7y1/R@2TxeZkqnheQdD1sQfaZAlwWtoxHBIg4MfPQ3SOXDEDYi2UpBJExhjXfA/lxBBPvh@IF6xJaeXksvGUueAH6qA9J04uiLUqJZUryN4W9OLhcegbzVur1G1WagfxptEFZabLhvxDuoO1/IL@DUviuBTgP8kyF2bGi8sDmdj26OkhAwoRm7b6rdoPLbm39qo@ou3VT14eklJruWb3nFduB9EjV4DmuYP38RF3sbjexcTaxmYtcr3/YTHu7xoZCeQ96QYv0CCp456xUabidufOFGt55q@DanBtGUzSzfBSgsXmjMIiCEL/ZwAoR9rG5Y6ux4dQ3wcm4c8JZZBkM@eb1TTVGMzRtK6YTP5r6705kRYYDh9YEjU3sV7oX9KBvw2683w)

```
# see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178303/find-if-a-list-is-an-abc-triple
^
(?!                # Verify that A and B are coprime. We don't need to include C in the
                   # test, because the requirement that A+B=C implies that A,B,C are
                   # mutually comprime if and only if A and B are coprime.
    (xx+)\1*,\1+,  # If this matches, A and B have a common factor \1 and aren't coprime.
)
(x*)(,\2x+)\3\2$   # Verify that A<B and A+B=C. The first comma is captured in \3 and
                   # reused to match the second comma, saving one byte.
```

The question does say "Three integers, *decimal* written", so this might not qualify (as it takes input in unary), but it makes for such an elegant pure regex that I hope it will at least be appreciated.

However, note that if the phrasing is to be literally interpreted, lambda and function submissions that take integer arguments are to be disqualified too, as to strictly adhere to the question's specification they would need to take the input in the form of a string.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 90 bytes

```cs
n=>new int[(int)1e8].Where((_,b)=>n[0]%++b<1&n[1]%b<1).Count()<2&n[0]+n[1]==n[2]&n[0]<n[1]
```

Runs for numbers up to 1e8, takes about 35 seconds on my machine. Instead of calculating the gcd like others, the function just instantiate a huge array and filter the indexes that aren't divisors of a or b, and check how many elements are left. Next it check if element one plus element two equals element three. Lastly, it checks if the first element is less than the second.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFBa8MgGL3nV3hpUeLKNNYYorkMduq9hxBGk1oqHQaSdCuU/PZMwxYY5vLxvve@5/vUpn9pejO9320jD6YfpLFDgeu2/SwearKqsPobOK6EriCiRbU7XnWnIfzANXJy@Vpt4riWZGtLUm0cQLu39m4HiCTdejn2glK2pNXcS99PefR16sBN@fPn4CW9eC6cb58EA4FBNuLoP08xSDDYr/GcJTxh5A8kwQzDgFDiS@ifBSao86X7X8QyHs45OwZ0jadrezk@c1dZ30WklAu6oDCNz69AWCCkLsv7xjGPLm2nT80V@qc9u28DNxQdOzPog7EaPuAZoXz6AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 59 bytes

```cs
(a,b,c)=>Enumerable.Range(2,a).All(i=>a%i+b%i>0)&a<b&a+b==c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BDsIgEEX3nqIbG4hjlSmlNEoTF7o23gBIa0iwTVp7/opGTVkAkzf/z3zsuLWjmy9TZ4@ue8LvmL73ddImaiYaDFiq6nM3PZpBG99kN93dG4KgaXbynjhV67XbmLWr9zTVR5PqjVHKzofVbpc8h6lZXYcwlbSEgYSK0sMfIORQxEDwXOScfd982eSQMGTvK/J8GJcY1GXxrXgl3pIQoNV@XCZggJEZME7AoAIZb2UoSxQSf4VYtkX4E@NLUkIRlIHMLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 27 bytes

```
(+/=2*{:)*({.<1{])*1=+./ .*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY69DsIwDIT3PsWJpW2K0tr5aVqRR2FCRIiFoWPUZw9BkIbB8n3y6c7PFDYvMWHFlLph9Czi2osuygvFay/ID3KEFKlvThJt8LLFGfuKsDXN/fZ4IYDgsBRgKJgKViurNP22KgcNYspzOD@oHWfLbL5CL7YWELgC1wLCAvcf6ma2jos4Emx@kXShGSY70hs)

Inspired by Jo King's Perl solution

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 30 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy).

```
(a,b,c)->a<b==gcd(a,b)&&a+b==c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc5LCoMwEADQqwwuxNBxkY8xgepFxEVMUQQpQbqwp08nIXUT3vwT3Lm3W4grDBAbhwt61o7uuQzD5l8pweraPSj00YVwfJsL2hHCub8/xCoFFXh3HM2KcDGGME0cwSDYmSwQJEJXqJXUUvE/ZEorBC54enJXtjKCqn1XpKzOJWpCEIWirCVaunevMr3QRtzKkzp/iKvknuZSdZ5Z/AE)

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##Pc5LCoMwEADQqwwuxNBxkY8xgepFxEVMUQQpQbqwp08nIXUT3vwT3Lm3W4grDBAbhwt61o7uuQzD5l8pweraPSj00YVwfJsL2hHCub8/xCoFFXh3HM2KcDGGME0cwSDYmSwQJEJXqJXUUvE/ZEorBC54enJXtjKCqn1XpKzOJWpCEIWirCVaunevMr3QRtzKkzp/iKvknuZSdZ5Z/AE)(?)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 68 bytes

Without Linq.

```cs
(a,b,c)=>{var t=a<b&a+b==c;while(b>0){c=b;b=a%b;a=c;}return t&a<2;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNS8QwEIbv/RXDgkvLxsWm36TpRfAmCB68eEnSUgvdRJJ0Rcr@9pquq@5F2iRMXpiH4WGEuRVKN9NgOtnC86exzYF4omfGwJNWrWaH0QN4H3jfCTCWWfcdVVfDI@ukH8xNgIdBinLolWzRdeVK9RXUQCefIY5EQKvxyDRYykq@ZTtOqSAfb13f@Ly6C0ZBOeGU3XDCXOOkGztoCXbLSkxOZPq2298raVTf7F90Zxu/9mMEIQ7nkgSwg82r3ATE@wd2XI6gWAYxgghBsgpM4yiN4vAnRCs0ZuE4xw7OkkuKi3SVv3t4FYhX@TuwcEtZBs97zjOc5vg3rTBOzxsP42Uyc77z5D8SLsc7uTt9AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü╡v╕7+Pü°╔|g
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81b576b8372b5081f8c97c67&i=[1,8,9]%0A[2,3,5]%0A[2,6436341,6436343]%0A[4,121,125]%0A[121,48234375,48234496]%0A%0A[1,1,2]%0A[1,2,5]%0A[1,9,8]%0A[4,12872682,12872686]%0A[6,8,14]%0A[7,5,12]&m=2)

Comment: By re-arranging slightly, you can get 11. https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8d4d0aa8fac1c545d0f061&i=[1,8,9]%0A[2,3,5]%0A[2,6436341,6436343]%0A[4,121,125]%0A[121,48234375,48234496]%0A%0A[1,1,2]%0A[1,2,5]%0A[1,9,8]%0A[4,12872682,12872686]%0A[6,8,14]%0A[7,5,12]&m=2

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 43 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$a b c=a<b&&a+b==c&&gcd a b<2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r4xLJVEhSSHZNtEmSU0tUTvJ1jZZTS09OUUBKGxj9D@4JBGo1FZBRcFQwULB8v@/5LScxPTi/7qePv9dKvMSczOTiwE)

Similar to basically everything else because the direct test is the same.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
\d+
$*
A`^(11+)\1*,\1+,
^(1+)(,1+\1)\2\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU05DgIxDOz9jkVKNm7Gca6Sik9YaJGgoKFA/D94OYo5PKORn7fX/XGZh3Dapl0TLSsdt3MAUjSsbEhMfqYYGMkQTQzLnODOg4QzF@equWbFTzMpQ@AotKt28bCVr9FRyTsWZ/E1eHD/LHqT2uVvKlX/AaXGxbM3) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Deadcode. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
A`^(11+)\1*,\1+,
```

Check that A and B have no common factor.

```
^(1+)(,1+\1)\2\1$
```

Check that A < B and A + B = C.

Comment: There appears to be a bug in your program. [121, 48234375, 48234496] is returning false.

Comment: @Deadcode Fixed, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: As with my regex, you can drop 1 byte by changing `^(1+),(1+\1),\1\2$` to `^(1+)(,1+\1)\2\1$`.

Comment: @Deadcode Thanks! It's a shame that my use of Retina's `A` operation doesn't actually save me any bytes.

Comment: Actually, I would say the main benefit is that you can move the `A`ntigrep operation (coprime assertion) *after* the part that simply asserts that A<B and A+B=C, because the latter will fail faster and benefit the overall average speed of the regex with random test cases. I'd suggest that move. I can't do it in my pure regex for obvious reasons.

Comment: Another speed optimization would be to change `(,1+\1)` to `(,\11+)` but you can't do that because `1` is your unary digit and it would be interpreted as `\11`.

Comment: @Deadcode I'm using Retina's behaviour of turning the last regex into a positive assertion (actually a (count of) match stage) so moving the antigrep would cost me 5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 83 bytes

```
&:&:03p&:04pw>03g04g\:v_1w03g04g+w1.@
00:    7j@.0[^j7      _^;>0.@;j7;>0.@;:%g00\p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X81KzcrAuABImBSU2xkYpxuYpMdYlcUblkPY2uWGeg5cBgZWCkBgnuWgZxAdl2WuAAbxcdZ2BnoO1lnmENpKNd3AIKbg/39LBQsFQwA)

The input which is a triple of integers `[A,B,C]` is feeded into Befunge as space-separated integers `C B A`.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 35 bytes

```
CoprimeQ @@ # && #[[1]] + #[[2]] == #[[3]] &
```

if order is important:

```
CoprimeQ @@ # && Sort[#]==# && #[[1]] + #[[2]] == #[[3]] &
```

or...

```
And[CoprimeQ @@ #, Sort@# == #, #[[1]] + #[[2]] == #[[3]]] &
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 51 bytes

```
(lambda(a b c)(and(< a b)(=(+ a b)c)(=(gcd a c)1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NTsMwEIRfZVQJsSsurOM4DlCOfQJuiINrF6iUNlUbDr341du1G9SDdz7PrH82DtvT4ULDOB7wPR5BAWtExnaPRyKBR88ggwZtVWcb11iZtVHPQozoKnkh640GXXsD27viQ2CqmnqPoIefz/rOOG/@oXQ7fVWsQodWfWakEaS/24UJExZZnhPuBVi@a8kvn6swnDZn5NeP49/0e85f@WGBOhBIZwy7dQrzgBT2id5KyLSkpwqx4E9MuokszHy59SpcAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `g`, 10 bytes

```
⟨ḣ¯=|Þ⇧|ġṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBZyIsIiIsIuKfqOG4o8KvPXzDnuKHp3zEoeG5hSIsIiIsIlsxLCAxLCAyXVxuWzEsIDIsIDVdXG5bMSwgOSwgOF1cbls0LCAxMjg3MjY4MiwgMTI4NzI2ODZdXG5bNiwgOCwgMTRdXG5bNywgNSwgMTJdIl0=)

Checks if the difference between the last two numbers equals the first one, if its sorted in ascending order, and if the gcd = 1